# ¿Como insertar pagina html con bootstrap css y js incluidos a wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

Hola muy buenas quisiera porfavor una ayuda para migrar una pagina con html css  js  y bootstrap a wordpress necesito insertar mis archivos html css y js a wordpress como si se tratara de una pagina nueva o talvez la misma pagina de inicio en pocas palabras tengo una pagina web terminada en html y quisiera pasar el codigo a wordpress jusnto con los archivos css js imagenes etc

- [Pagina en Wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75nB6.png)
- [Mi pagina html con bootstrap css y js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lI18.jpg)

Comment: Que tal, Bienvenido a [ES.so], por favor lee [ask] ya que tu pregunta es demasiado grande y difícilmente alguien se dará el tiempo de darte una respuesta completa. Por mi parte de invito a verte esta lista de reproducción youtube.com/watch?v=_nQZ8YhuCII&list=PLaNBgK4b74m5rKUfdFNPLc43ZuxZeQlC5 que explica un poco lo que quieres, tampoco esta de mas que hagas el [tour].

Comment: hola ya modifique la pregunta ,hechare  un vistazo a la lista de reproduccion gracias